# Передача объекта из активности в фрагмент

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Друзья!

Имеется активность ItemActivity, где контент формируется с использованием 3х фрагментов:

cardSliderFragment, cardMainInfoFragment, cardViewPagerFragment

В ItemActivity я получаю с вебсервиса json строку и преобразую в объект (item). Получаю с помощью асинхронного запроса через интерфейс.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);

        RemoteDataRequest dataRequest = new RemoteDataRequest("get_item", itemId);
        dataRequest.setOnFinishedListener(new RemoteDataRequest.OnFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFinished(StringBuffer stringBuffer) {
                try {
                    JSONObject item = new JSONObject(stringBuffer.toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        //Запускаем асинхронный запрос
        dataRequest.execute();


    }
```

Подскажите, каким образом я могу передать объект item во фрагменты? Есть конечно вариант внутри каждого фрагмента сделать асинхронный запрос (RemoteDataRequest), но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не совсем правильное решение.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из способов - перегнать весь JSONObject в string и передавать его через bundle при работе с фрагментами. В bundle положить данные можно так:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("identifier", string_data);
```

дальше как отослать в фрагмент:

```
FragmentClass fragInfo = new FragmentClass();
fragInfo.setArguments(b);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_single, fragInfo);
transaction.commit();
```

и дальше ловим данные в фрагменте:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(bundle.getString("identifier"));
```

Либо еще как вариант - сделать один класс, где будет объект `item`. Вы его получили и дальше сетите в переменную данные. Когда они вам понадобились вы их оттуда берете, когда нужно что-то поменять то меняете. То есть действует по принципу временного хранилища ваших данных.

Comment: Пошел по первому пути. Положил строку во вновь созданный объект Bundle, далее отослал в фрагмент и транзакцией заменил старый на новый, после чего произвел коммит. Здесь все ок. При попытке "отловить" аргумент уже в фрагменте: String identifier = bundle.getString("identifier"); получаю ошибку: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rosfixator/com.example.rosfixator.ItemActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class fragment

Answer (score 0):

Аргументы это хорошо, а вот то что фрагмент будет заниматься не своим делом, это плохо. Во первых: в java есть такая вещь как Serializable, google постарались и написали Parcelable [(рекомендуют его)](https://habr.com/ru/post/174015/). Парсите обьект на своём слое, потом передаёте тем же бандлом только уже готовый объект, при том что вы его уже передаёте только из активности в фрагмент.

Но вернёмся к вопросу хорошо и плохо, открываем гугл про андроит а именн [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) вариант [ру](https://habr.com/ru/post/456256/). Тут рассказывается об одном из подходов рекомендуемых гуглом для построения архитектуры мобильных приложений. Исходя из этого мы понимаем что каждый экран должен содержать свой ViewModel, не зависимо от того это активити, фрагмент или даже диалог (диалоги подразумеваются полностью функцианальные, а не просто да/нет). Приорганизации их выполнения через ViewModelFactory и по гайду, то утечек быть не должно, а это значит мы спокойно можем инжектить в наш VM ссылку на репозиторий и идти хоть в БД, хоть на бек за данными.